# Structs with variations - idiomatic way to represent

Tags: go

What is the best idiomatic way to represent a struct which has variations for types ?

For example, say I have:

```
type A struct {
  This []string
  That int32
}
```

But I might also need to represent it as:

```
type A struct {
   This string
   That int32
}
```

Is there an idiomatic way to represent both variations with a single type ?

Comment: A type can only have one definition. You could make it `That interface{}` but I wouldn't recommend it; it would make the rest of your code much clunkier.

Answer (score 0):

To me if your structure is able to accept a slice of This at any point in time then the first definition should always be the one you go for since a single item can be seen as a subset of a collection.

You could add functions to this structure to make it easier for the developers to interact with the structure though, but to me this looks fine as it is.